# Cannot script stored procedure while restoring another copy of current db

Tags: sql-server, ssms, scripting

I have some large DB that I need to restore to another db from time to time, this process take some time to conclude. The annoying thing I found out in last version of SSMS is that I cannot script any sp of the current db while I do this restore.

In my case I have the current db named `FleetXS` that is online and is in use and I do the restore of backup of this db with the date of 2 days ago in other db named `Fleetxs_Restore`. For all the time of the restore it's not possible to script any sp of db `FleetXS` with the weird error

> Cannot open database "FLEETXS_restore" requested by the login. The
> login failed. Login failed for user 'anna'. (Microsoft SQL Server,
> Error: 4060)

[image: login failed]

I have no need to open the database `FLEETXS_restore` that even is not actual to date, I operate within my current database `FleetXS` that is online, why on the earth my login "requested db `FLEETXS_restore`"? Is there any workaround or should I wait for hours when the restore finishes to be able to get the text of sp of **another** database?

[image: sp scripting]

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU10) (KB5001090) - 15.0.4123.1 (X64)
> Mar 22 2021 18:10:24    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0
>  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

- SQL Server Management Studio                     15.0.18390.0
- SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)              16.100.46521.71
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools         15.0.19714.0
- Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC)           10.0.19041.1
- Microsoft MSXML                      3.0 6.0
- Microsoft .NET Framework         4.0.30319.42000
- Operating System                 10.0.19043

I do not use SSMS to do the restore, I use my own script. There are two backups to restore, full + diff. I do full with norecovery and diff with recovery.

Comment: Seems like a bad design in SSMS. How about do the scripting from Powershell, using SMO, instead? I have done that for a case I had, picked up some PS/SMO code "from internet". :-)

Comment: Please add your restore script to the post.

Comment: @J.D. Sincerely I don't see any relation between my restore script and SSMS behaviour, it seems that SSMS just make a loop and try co connect to all databases in order to produce a script of just 1 object of 1 current database. I already answer your question about RECOVERY and NORECOVERY options that, in any way, cannot induce SSMS to go to other databases

Comment: SSMS is just a client application that executes T-SQL (mostly) just the same as if you executed the code yourself. So I think it's a low likelihood (though not impossible) that SSMS is your problem. Having your restore script would be useful because sometimes restoring to a new database still affects the previous database that the backup came from, depending on the restore options used. One example is the "*Leave **source database** in the restoring state*" option, which is different from the "NORECOVERY" option you mentioned, so you haven't answered my question. I'm no expert on database...

Comment: ...restores, but given what I know and mentioned about the source database potentially being affected during a restore, and the fact we have nothing else to go off of, your best bet for help here would be to update your question with your restore script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `sp_helptext` stored procedure.

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: This works well (it is not sp_help_text but sp_helptext) but it works as any other code that is not generated by SSMS. As I said, my current db is online and completely operational so any code that reguards only this db works. The question is what code does SSMS do to make a script of one object and why it goes to other databases and how to make it avoid going to other databases. I personally can use this sp but we have many other colleagues that get used to use GUI...